# How can I loop 2 or more changing variables without Selection in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having a hard time solving a problem. I've just recently started coding and I would like to create a macro that checks 3 variables (1 for date and 2 for position) without using the Selection function.

What I'm trying to achieve is to have a cell that checks 1 cell with a date (A) to determine if the date is before today and if the cell is not blank. It would either write "Expired" (if the date is before today) or the text in the cell to the left.

It would then move on to the below cells and do this again. Even though this works, it is very slow and I was wondering if there was any other method I could use to speed this up (at 8000 lines this is really not worth it). Maybe use a filter?

Any help is much appreciated!

```
Dim status As String
Dim exp As Date
Dim i As Integer
Dim n As Integer
Dim m As Integer


i = 0
n = 1
status = 1
m = 1

Do While status <> ""

    Cells.Find(What:="A", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas _
        , LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    ActiveCell.Offset(n, 0).Select

    exp = Selection

    Cells.Find(What:="B", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas _
        , LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

   ActiveCell.Offset(m, 0).Select



    status = ActiveCell.Offset(i, -1).Value

    MsgBox (status)

    If exp <> 0 And exp < Date Then
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Expired"
    Else
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = status
    End If

    i = i - 1
    n = n + 1
    m = m + 1

Loop
```

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phMlC.png)

EDIT: I think this more or less shows what I would like to do in a simple way. The aim is to only change the Status text when the date is before today. However, there could be additional columns (like Amount) so I would like to avoid static ranges and in case of 25000 rows the selection method is VERRRY slow. I do feel like I've overcomplicated this a bit with the do while.

Comment: Can you screenshot what the sheet looks like? This should be relatively simple, but I would like to see what exactly you are expecting first. This actually sounds like you can  just use formulas.

Comment: Here's the screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/phMlC.png
I've edited the OP to contain a bit more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come up with some codings that is more suitable to the case you presented:

It will set up some testing data on a new workbook, and no column address is hardcoded.

It will also shows how to create a listobject and refer to its various elements in an object oriented way and without hard-coding address

Finally it uses the filter capability of the listobject to perform the filtering (it is more or less the same as the sheet-based autofilter)

Run the Main() sub to start the demo.

```
Const COL_FRUIT As String = "Fruit", COL_FRESHUNTIL As String = "Fresh Until", COL_STATUSTEXT = "Status text"
Dim POS_FRUIT As Integer, POS_FRESHUNTIL As Integer, POS_STATUSTEXT As Integer


Sub Main()
    Dim lo As ListObject
    SetupData lo
    lo.ListColumns(COL_FRUIT).Range.Select
    MsgBox "Fruit column"

    lo.ListRows(2).Range.Select
    MsgBox "2nd row"

    lo.ListColumns(COL_FRUIT).DataBodyRange.Select
    MsgBox "Fruit data"

    lo.Range.AutoFilter Field:=POS_FRESHUNTIL, Criteria1:= _
        "<4/1/2018", Operator:=xlAnd
    lo.Range.AutoFilter Field:=POS_STATUSTEXT, Criteria1:= _
        "=*exp*", Operator:=xlAnd

    MsgBox "Filter applied: " & vbCrLf & _
    "Row 1 matched: " & (lo.ListRows(1).Range.Height <> 0) & vbCrLf & _
    "Row 2 matched: " & (lo.ListRows(2).Range.Height <> 0) & vbCrLf & _
    "Row 3 matched: " & (lo.ListRows(3).Range.Height <> 0)
End Sub
Sub SetupData(ByRef ref_lo As ListObject)
    Dim newwb As Workbook, currsh As Worksheet, vData As Variant, rData As Range, lo As ListObject
    Set newwb = Workbooks.Add
    Set currsh = newwb.Worksheets(1)
    Dim s As String
    vData = [{"Fruit", "Fresh Until", "Status text"; "Apple","03-03-2018","Fresh";"Apple","03-12-2017","Expired";"Apple","03-12-2017","Date over"}]
    POS_FRUIT = GetColPos(COL_FRUIT, vData)
    POS_FRESHUNTIL = GetColPos(COL_FRESHUNTIL, vData)
    POS_STATUSTEXT = GetColPos(COL_STATUSTEXT, vData)        

    Set rData = currsh.Cells(1).Resize(UBound(vData, 1), UBound(vData, 2))
    rData = vData
    Set ref_lo = currsh.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, rData, , xlYes)     ' or ListObjects("name_of_your_listobject")        

End Sub

Function GetColPos(sCol As String, data As Variant) As Integer
    Dim ifr As Integer, ito As Integer, i As Integer
    ito = UBound(data, 2)
    ifr = LBound(data, 2)
    For i = ifr To ito
        If sCol = data(LBound(data, 1), i) Then
            GetColPos = i
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next

     GetColPos = -1

End Function
```

Comment: to write value back to the listobject (e.g. write to status text): lo.ListRows(1).Range.cells(POS_STATUSTEXT) = "Expired"

Comment: Thank you very much, this seems to be it. I'll have to work with it a bit as it's a bit above my head right now, but the help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can grab all the values of a range object to a 2d array variable, and you work on the array instead. It is WAY MUCH faster

E.g. let's say you have many different values in the range a1:c6, you need to loop thru the values

```
Dim var2d As Variant, r As Range
Set r = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:C6")
var2d = r   ' var2d becomes a 6x3 array
Msgbox var2d(2,1) ' print value of cell A2
var2d(3,2) = "Expired"
var2d(5,1) = 123
r.Value = var2d  ' write the modified array back to a1:c6
```

Comment: Perhaps explain that this cryptic `[a1:c6]` notation is shorthand code for `Application.Evaluate("A1:C6")`, which is kind of a roundabout and inefficient way to refer to `ActiveSheet.Range("A1:C6")`?

Comment: What I only know is It's an efficient way for me to type on a smartphone :) also if you read that it can be SET to a Range variable you'll know that the notation evaluates as a range object

Comment: Thanks for the response! I haven't used a 2d array before, can the If Then Else get values/dates from this?
I was also wondering if it were easier to just use an Autofilter to filter for the dates before today, that would exclude blank cells and I wouldn't need a 3rd column.

Comment: Of course! After you put x/y indices to an array it would act like an ordinary variable. Try changing all "cells" collection reference to "usedrange.cells", because "cells" means all cells of the sheet, but usedrange.cells doesn't include cells that are beyond the sheet's "last cell", see if it's faster

Comment: Try to open a sheet with that 25000 rows, and try "msgbox cells.count" and "msgbox usedrange.cells.count", you'll see what I mean

Comment: Wow, it really is a lot faster, but unfortunately it's still slow. Manually filtering dates before today end writing Expired into the last column is still a lot faster. I've also noticed that "status" does not update as the Macro goes.
To be honest, I started looking into filtering as that seems to be an easier solution, I feel like I've overcomplicated this a bit. I've edited the OP, I think you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Is it that your problem is you don't know how to programmatically do the auto filter? Use the macro recorder, you can get the corresponding VBA code

Comment: If your concern is the hardcoding of the cell address, try using the list object. Select the table including the column names and press CTRL-T, and check "has column names", to create a list object. Then you can refer to entire columns using column names. I'm not at my computer so I'm not able to show you codings, unfortunately. I'll do so at a convenient time

Comment: You don't need to use activate () and select () and then read Selection, it's a performance killer for scalability (unless you only call it just a few times). You should use "dim r as range : set r = .find(...)" And then get the value you want using e.g. "r.cells(n, 1)". Also, using "application.screenupdating = false" will make things a bit faster. Set it back to true when you're done

Comment: Thanks for all these, I'll have a look at them tomorrow on my work computer. I realised that I originally used the IF function that is why I needed the "status" variable. However, now that I'm using if-then-else I only need to change the entries in the Status text column to "Expired" if the date is before today and nothing else needs to be done with entries where the date is after today.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
Dim status As String
Dim exp As Date
Dim i As Integer
Dim n As Integer
Dim m As Integer

Dim c As Range, d As Range

i = 0
n = 1
status = 1
m = 1

With ActiveSheet
    Set d = .Range("A1")
    Do While status <> ""
        Set c = .Cells.Find(what:="A", after:=d, LookIn:=xlFormulas _
                , LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            exp = c.Offset(n, 0).Value2
            Set d = .Cells.Find(what:="B", after:=c.Offset(n, 0), LookIn:=xlFormulas _
                    , LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
            If Not d Is Nothing Then
                With d.Offset(m + i, -1)
                    .Select
                    status = .Value2
                    MsgBox status

                    If exp <> 0 And exp < Date Then
                        .Value2 = "Expired"
                    Else
                        .Value2 = status
                    End If
                End With
            End If
        End If

        i = i - 1
        n = n + 1
        m = m + 1
    Loop
End With
```

Comment: I went with another solution, but thanks for the help, much appreciated!